# What is the difference between "manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns" and "manage_edit-{$post_type}_columns"?

Tags: query-posts

What is the difference between **`manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns`** and **`manage_edit-{$post_type}_columns`**?

Could somebody explain what is the difference between these two approaches?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the way the admin post table is constructed. WordPress uses a class `WP_Posts_List_Table` to generate and handle that table. You'll notice that there are a few tables in the admin area similar: Plugins, Terms, Users, etc. They each are their own class, but they all extend from a base class of `WP_List_Table`.

`manage_edit-{$post_type}_columns` is a more generic filter that is set (but not called) in `WP_List_Table`. And, it is actually `manage_{$screen->id}_columns`. The callback is the `get_columns` method for the table object.

```
add_filter( "manage_{$this->screen->id}_columns", array( &$this, 'get_columns' ), 0 );
```

This filter is used by the `get_column_headers()` function for retrieving the columns.

So where does `manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns` then? Remember the method `get_columns()` that is call for the filter `manage_{$screen->id}_columns`, the `WP_Posts_List_Table` class over-rides the base method from `WP_List_Table`. In `WP_Posts_List_Table::get_columns()` is where the filter `manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns` is called.

To recap:

1. A `WP_Posts_List_Table` object is created
2. It's parent class `WP_List_Table` adds `$this->get_columns()` to the hook `manage_{$screen->id}_columns`
3. The function `get_column_headers()` calls the filter `manage_{$screen->id}_columns`
4. `WP_Posts_List_Table` has over-ridden the method `get_columns()`
5. Inside of `WP_Posts_List_Table::get_columns()`, it calls the filter `manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns` **This is where your manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns hook would run**
6. `WP_Posts_List_Table::get_columns()` will return the columns and then run the remaining filters for `manage_{$screen->id}_columns`

Which one should you use? I don't know. We know that `manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns` can only be called for post types, whereas `manage_edit-{$post_type}_columns` may match a different admin page (although I'm not sure if it would).

Answer (score 0):

They both essentially do the same thing.

`manage_edit-{$post_type}_columns` used to be the old recommended hook used to create or change columns for custom posts types.

With WordPress 3.1 (23 February 2011), `manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns` was added and is now the recommended hook to use.

Here is a quote from the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_edit-post_type_columns):

> In WP 3.1, manage_edit-{$post_type}_columns has been supplanted by manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns.

*supplant = supersede and replace.*

Although the old hook is not deprecated, the new hook is the one to use now.